# What server does jhipster use?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster, servlet-container

I know you can build a WAR file to deploy to an application server, but what kind of server is created when you run the main Application class?

```
/**
 * Main method, used to run the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
    SimpleCommandLinePropertySource source = new SimpleCommandLinePropertySource(args);
    addDefaultProfile(app, source);
    Environment env = app.run(args).getEnvironment();
    log.info("Access URLs:\n-----------------------------------------------------\n\t" +
            "Local: \t\thttp://127.0.0.1:{}\n\t" +
            "External: \thttp://{}:{}\n-----------------------------------------------",
        env.getProperty("server.port"),
        InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(),
        env.getProperty("server.port"));
}
```

Comment: By default spring-boot uses Tomcat. You can configure it to use Jetty or undertow(https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html). You can check your pom.xml and see if there are any references to them. If not, you can assume, it is tomcat.

Comment: Thanks. If you put this as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default Spring Boot uses Tomcat. You can configure it to use [Jetty or Undertow](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html) as embedded container. You can check your `pom.xml` and see if there are any references to them. If not, you can assume, it is Tomcat

Comment: And I (the author of JHipster) confirm it's Tomcat.

Comment: As of JHipster 3.7.0 (Ref http://www.jhipster.tech/2016/09/12/jhipster-release-3.7.0.html and https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/4054) it's Undertow.

Answer (score 5):

After version of 3.7.0 JHipster migrated to **Undertow**. The release note says:

> **Migration to Undertow** is our biggest change - see [#4054](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/4054). This brings some very good performance enhancements in start up time and memory usage: this is good for everyone, but people doing microservices will benefit from it even more. With this change, JHipster uses nearly as much JBoss code (Undertow, Hibernate, Bean Validation, MapStruct) as Spring code!

For more information visit [here](https://www.jhipster.tech/2016/09/12/jhipster-release-3.7.0.html)